# How to keep the Class Togggled after refreshing the page (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello Guys How are you ?
I'm working on project and I have a simple Question How to keep the Class Togggled after refreshing the page using jQuery ??

whenever you press the button it works fine, but upon page reload it reverts back to the before toggled state. How might I fix this issue, open to any solution preferably client side? (Below is a snippet of my button and the code alongside it)

**JS Code :**

```
    $(document).on("click", "#toggle_the_div", function toggleDiv(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Change Toggle Icon
        $('.icon_toggler').find('.ion').toggleClass('ion-md-radio-button-off ion-md-radio-button-on');
        if ($('.icon_toggler').find('.ion').hasClass('ion-md-radio-button-on')) {
            $($(this)).css("color", "var(--primary)");
        } else if ($('.icon_toggler').find('.ion').hasClass('ion-md-radio-button-off')) {
            $($(this)).css("color", "var(--dark)");
        }
        // Toggle Activation
        $('#hellodiv').toggleClass('is_toggled');
        if (localStorage.getItem('switch-state') && localStorage.getItem('switch-state') === "true") {
            //
        }
    });
```

**HTML Code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/4.6.3/css/ionicons.min.css">

    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #hellodiv .is_toggled {
        background: red;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <button type="button" id="toggle_the_div" class="btn btn-light">
   <span class="icon_toggler mr-1"><i class="ion ion-md-radio-button-off"></i></span> Toggle Now
   </button>
   <div class="D1" id="hellodiv">
   <h1>Hello World</h1>
   </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're going to have to preserve a reference to what the state should be some how, and restore it on load.  One approach is to use sessionStorage or localStorage.

Comment: can you rewrite the good please ?

Comment: Since you want to save state, you'll need to set/check for a cookie (or localStorage) in your javascript. Onclick will set the cookie, on each pageload, you'd check if the cookie exists. If it does, set your class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099361/keep-toggle-state-of-menu-using-jquery

Comment: please guys anyone can rewrite the code please

Comment: We're not here to rewrite code.  You've asked a pretty broad question.  You need to make an attempt first, and then if you run into issues edit your question to ask about your issues.

Comment: @HoussamHammouda - no, that's not a free code writing service

Comment: o din't ask for free service only simple help

Comment: anyone can help ?